# How to save files selected by a list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of 3 files with its associated checkboxes. The user select 2 checkboxes and click on save button. A save to folder dialog opens for the user to save the files.

This is my code:

```
if(!empty($listeDocTypeClientProjet))
{
    $iGroups = 0;
    while($iGroups < count($listeDocTypeClientProjet))
    {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td style='text-align: left;'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="docTypeSelect[]" class="files" id="docTypeSelect_<?php echo $listeDocTypeClientProjet[$iGroups]->DOC_TYPE_ID ?>" value="<?php echo $listeDocTypeClientProjet[$iGroups]->DOC_TYPE_ID ?>"> <?php echo $listeDocTypeClientProjet[$iGroups]->DOC_TYPE_NOM ?>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <?php
    $iGroups++;
    }
}
```

I dont know how to proceed with the save button. Can anyone pls point me in the right direction.

Here is what ive done so far:

```
function SaveDocType(client_projet_id, client_id)
{

    var fileIds = $('.files:checked').each(function() {
        window.open('test3.php?file=' + $(this).next('label').text());
    });

}
```